# how to delete the rows of data which is repeating in Pig

Tags: dataset, filtering, apache-pig

> "YouTube Rewind: The Shape of 2017 | #YouTubeRewind"  137843120   3014479 1602383 817582
>
> "YouTube Rewind: The Shape of 2017 | #YouTubeRewind"  125431369   2912715 1545018 807558
>
> "YouTube Rewind: The Shape of 2017 | #YouTubeRewind"  113876217   2811217 1470387 787174
>
> "YouTube Rewind: The Shape of 2017 | #YouTubeRewind"  100911567   2656678 1353655 682890
>
> "Marvel Studios' Avengers: Infinity War Official Trailer" 89930713    2606665 53011   347982
>
> "Marvel Studios' Avengers: Infinity War Official Trailer" 87450245    2584675 52176   341571
>
> "Marvel Studios' Avengers: Infinity War Official Trailer" 84281319    2555414 51008   339708
>
> "Marvel Studios' Avengers: Infinity War Official Trailer" 80360459    2513103 49170   335920
>
> "YouTube Rewind: The Shape of 2017 | #YouTubeRewind"  75969469    2251826 1127811 827755
>
> "Marvel Studios' Avengers: Infinity War Official Trailer" 74789251    2444960 46172   330710
>
> "Marvel Studios' Avengers: Infinity War Official Trailer" 66637636    2331359 41154   316185
>
> "Marvel Studios' Avengers: Infinity War Official Trailer" 56367282    2157741 34078   303178
>
> "YouTube Rewind: The Shape of 2017 | #YouTubeRewind"  52611730    1891822 884963  702784
>
> "To Our Daughter" 51243149    0   0   0
>
> "To Our Daughter" 48635732    0   0   0

in above data there is 2 columns one is "title" and other are views, likes, dislikes, comment_count.

how to use filter and remove repeating data
i want to remove the data which is having same "title: and keep the data with highest views

Answer (score 0):

the data is having 15 cols i selected the 5 cols which are mentioned in the question
'select_specified_columns' defines the above asked table

> only_likes = foreach select_specified_columns generate $0,$1;
>
> store only_likes into 'test/only_likes';
>
> group_likes = group only_likes by $0;
>
> store group_likes into 'test/group_likes';
>
> max_likes = foreach group_likes generate group , MAX(only_likes.views);
>
> store max_likes into 'test/max_likes';
>
> result_likes = order max_likes by $1 DESC;
>
> store result_likes into 'test/result_likes';

i did that using following commands

Comment: This approach is fine if you simply want the MAX likes for a given title. However, if you want to retain other fields as well for the record corresponding to MAX likes, have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain all fields of the record corresponding to the MAX likes, you would have to do something like so:

```
dataAll = LOAD 'path' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (title:chararray, views:long, likes:long, dislikes:long, comment_count:long);

--group the data by title so that all records belonging to a title fall into a bag in the same record
dataGrouped = GROUP dataAll BY title;

--Using a nested foreach, order the contents of the bag by likes and pick the top record
dataDeduped = FOREACH dataGrouped {
                 soredtedByLikes = ORDER dataAll BY likes DESC;
                 maxLikesRecord = LIMIT soredtedByLikes 1;
                 GENERATE FLATTEN(maxLikesRecord);
              }

STORE dataDeduped INTO 'outputPath' USING PigStorage('\t');
```

Nested Foreach comes in pretty useful in such situations. Checkout more about it here: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-pig/9781449317881/ch06.html (Search for nested foreach in that link).