# How to get the first tuple inside a bag when Grouping

Tags: apache-pig

I do not understand how to deal with duplicates when generating my output, so I ended up getting several duplicates but I want one only.

I've tried using LIMIT but that only applies when selecting I suppose. I also used DISTINCT but wrong scenario I guess.

```
grouped = GROUP wantedTails BY tail_number;

smmd = FOREACH grouped GENERATE wantedTails.tail_number as Tails, SUM(wantedTails.distance) AS totaldistance;
```

So for my grouped, I got smg like (not the whole):
({(N983JB),(N983JB),(N983JB),(N983JB),(N983JB),(N983JB),(N983JB),(N983JB),(N983JB),(N983JB),(N983JB),(N983JB),(N983JB),(N983JB),(N983JB),(N983JB),(N983JB),(N983JB)},44550)

but I expect (N983JB,44550). How can I delete those duplicates generated during grouping? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I made a type, it should be "So for my smmd"

Comment: You you have a edit button

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to include all your relevant source code, and a sample of your input data, so that the community can replicate your problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, there are two ways to de-duplicate data in Pig.

1. Less flexible but a convenient way is to apply `MAX` to the columns which need to be de-duplicated after performing a `GROUP BY`. Apply `SUM` only if you want to add up values across duplicates:

   ```
   dataWithDuplicates = LOAD '<path_to_data>';

   grouped = GROUP dataWithDuplicates BY tail_number;

   dedupedData= FOREACH grouped GENERATE
             --Since you have grouped on tailNumber, it is already de-duped
             group AS tailNumber, 
             MAX(dataWithDuplicates.distance) AS dedupedDistance,
             SUM(dataWithDuplicates.distance) AS totalDistance;
   ```
2. If you want more flexibility while de-duping, you can take help of nested-`FOREACH` in Pig. This question captures the gist of its usage: [how to delete the rows of data which is repeating in Pig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49952446/how-to-delete-the-rows-of-data-which-is-repeating-in-pig/49954010#49954010). Other references for nested-FORACH: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-pig/9781449317881/ch06.html